# How to get Steam game install/save file path programmatically?

Tags: files, steam

Some Steam games don't have cloud backup support, so I'm using a Git repo with a Makefile to create backups of game save files and settings. Because of storage restrictions I've had to create an additional Steam library folder. That is, some of my games are stored in `/home/username/.local/share/Steam`, while others are in `/mnt/games/SteamLibrary`. I'd like for the Makefile to deal with this automatically, so I don't have to hard code the current install path. In many cases the save folder is within the Steam library, so that's the main question:

**How do I get the install directory using either the game ID or name?**

I'm *not* looking for manual solutions like looking through the Steam GUI or slow/brittle solutions like `find / -type d -name GAME_ID`. Parsing and looping over the output of `steamcmd +library_folder_list +quit` would be horrible, but possible as a last resort.

### Bonus question

Some games *don't* put their saves in the same directory. For example, Hollow Knight saves and settings are in `~/.config/unity3d/Team Cherry/Hollow Knight`. I don't expect Steam knows about this directory, but if it does and you know how to get it, that would certainly be worth a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

`.steam/root/steamapps/libraryfolders.vdf` should contain a block for each library folder and the appids of the games/programs installed in that library.

`.steam/root/steamapps/appmanifest_<appid>.acf` contains a name-field with the name corresponding to an appid.

I'm pretty sure, the settings for game-save-files are game-specifig setting, not somewhere configured in steam. So I can't help with the bonus-question, I'm afraight.

Comment: Thanks! This gets a little bit closer, but as far as I can tell only tells me which Steam library root folder each game is in.